# Understand how to update riverpod 2.0 NotifierProvider in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I think I have done this correct but please let me know if I have not. I don't know if I need everything in the class or not. I am having trouble finding documentation or examples similar to this.

This is my globals class and notifier class:

```
class Globals {
  final String? currentUid;
  final String? currentUEmail;
  final String? userDocumentId;
  final String? companyId;
  final String? mlsId;
  final String? currentTrxnId;
  final String? currentCompanyName;
  final String? currentCompanyState;
  final String? currentUserId;
  final String? currentUserState;
  final String? currentUserName;
  final String? selectedState;
  final String? selectedUserState;
  final String? selectedTrxnState;
  final String? selectedCompany;
  final String? selectedUser;
  final String? targetScreen;
  final bool? newEvent;
  final bool? newTrxn;
  final bool? newUser;
  final bool? newCompany;

  Globals(
      {this.currentUid,
      this.currentUEmail,
      this.userDocumentId,
      this.companyId,
      this.mlsId,
      this.currentTrxnId,
      this.currentCompanyName,
      this.currentCompanyState,
      this.currentUserId,
      this.currentUserState,
      this.currentUserName,
      this.selectedState,
      this.selectedUserState,
      this.selectedTrxnState,
      this.selectedCompany,
      this.selectedUser,
      this.targetScreen,
      this.newEvent,
      this.newTrxn,
      this.newUser,
      this.newCompany});

  Globals copyWith({
    String? currentUid,
    String? currentUEmail,
    String? userDocumentId,
    String? companyId,
    String? mlsId,
    String? currentTrxnId,
    String? currentCompanyName,
    String? currentCompanyState,
    String? currentUserId,
    String? currentUserState,
    String? currentUserName,
    String? selectedState,
    String? selectedUserState,
    String? selectedTrxnState,
    String? selectedCompany,
    String? selectedUser,
    String? targetScreen,
    bool? newEvent,
    bool? newTrxn,
    bool? newUser,
    bool? newCompany,
  }) {
    return Globals(
      currentUid: currentUid ?? this.currentUid,
      currentUEmail: currentUEmail ?? this.currentUEmail,
      userDocumentId: userDocumentId ?? this.userDocumentId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      currentTrxnId: currentTrxnId ?? this.currentTrxnId,
      currentCompanyName: currentCompanyName ?? this.currentCompanyName,
      currentCompanyState: currentCompanyState ?? this.currentCompanyState,
      currentUserId: currentUserId ?? this.currentUserId,
      currentUserState: currentUserState ?? this.currentUserState,
      currentUserName: currentUserName ?? this.currentUserName,
      selectedState: selectedState ?? this.selectedState,
      selectedUserState: selectedUserState ?? this.selectedUserState,
      selectedTrxnState: selectedTrxnState ?? this.selectedTrxnState,
      selectedCompany: selectedCompany ?? this.selectedCompany,
      selectedUser: selectedUser ?? this.selectedUser,
      targetScreen: targetScreen ?? this.targetScreen,
      newEvent: newEvent ?? this.newEvent,
      newTrxn: newTrxn ?? this.newTrxn,
      newUser: newUser ?? this.newUser,
      newCompany: newCompany ?? this.newCompany,
    );
  }
}

class GlobalsNotifier extends Notifier<Globals> {

  @override
  Globals build() {
    return Globals(
        currentUid: '',
        currentUEmail: '',
        userDocumentId: '',
        companyId: '',
        mlsId: '',
        currentTrxnId: '',
        currentCompanyName: '',
        currentCompanyState: '',
        currentUserId: '',
        currentUserName: '',
        currentUserState: '',
        selectedCompany: '',
        selectedState: '',
        selectedTrxnState: '',
        selectedUser: '',
        selectedUserState: '',
        targetScreen: '',
        newCompany: true,
        newEvent: true,
        newTrxn: true,
        newUser: true);
  }

  // functions to update class members
  void updatecurrentUid(String newcurrentUid) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUid: newcurrentUid);
  }

  void updatecurrentUEmail(String newcurrentUEmail) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUEmail: newcurrentUEmail);
  }

  void updateuserDocumentId(String newuserDocumentId) {
    state = state.copyWith(userDocumentId: newuserDocumentId);
  }

  void updatecompanyId(String newcompanyId) {
    state = state.copyWith(companyId: newcompanyId);
  }

  void updatemlsId(String newmlsId) {
    state = state.copyWith(mlsId: newmlsId);
  }

  void updatecurrentTrxnId(String newcurrentTrxnId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentTrxnId: newcurrentTrxnId);
  }

  void updatecurrentCompanyName(String newcurrentCompanyName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentCompanyName: newcurrentCompanyName);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserId(String newcurrentUserId) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserId: newcurrentUserId);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserState(String newcurrentUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserState: newcurrentUserState);
  }

  void updatecurrentUserName(String newcurrentUserName) {
    state = state.copyWith(currentUserName: newcurrentUserName);
  }

  void updateselectedState(String newselectedState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedState: newselectedState);
  }

  void updateselectedUserState(String newselectedUserState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUserState: newselectedUserState);
  }

  void updateselectedTrxnState(String newselectedTrxnState) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedTrxnState: newselectedTrxnState);
  }

  void updateselectedCompany(String newselectedCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedCompany: newselectedCompany);
  }

  void updateselectedUser(String newselectedUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(selectedUser: newselectedUser);
  }

  void updatetargetScreen(String newtargetScreen) {
    state = state.copyWith(targetScreen: newtargetScreen);
  }

  void updatenewEvent(bool newNewEvent) {
    state = state.copyWith(newEvent: newNewEvent);
  }

  void updatenewTrxn(bool newNewTrxn) {
    state = state.copyWith(newTrxn: newNewTrxn);
  }

  void updatenewUser(bool newNewUser) {
    state = state.copyWith(newUser: newNewUser);
  }

  void updatenewCompany(bool newNewCompany) {
    state = state.copyWith(newCompany: newNewCompany);
  }
}
```

Here is where I am trying to use it.
I get an error on the .new in the first line where I declare globalProvider.
**ERROR: The getter 'new' isn't defined for the type 'dynamic'.**
I also have an error on globalProvider.
**ERROR: The type of 'globalProvider' can't be inferred because it depends on itself through the cycle: globalProvider.**

In getCurrentAgencyName, I don't know how to update the state through the provider. I don't know if I have declared the variable globals correctly.
**final globals = ref.watch(globalProvider);**
I don't get an error even though I get one above.

```
// Create the global provider
// This provider represents the Notifier in global_provider.dart
final globalProvider = NotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(globalProvider.new);

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'login_screen';

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //ref.watch(globalProvider); // gives access to ref
    super.initState();
  }

  late String email;
  late String password;

  getCurrentAgencyName() async {
    final globals = ref.watch(globalProvider);
    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgentProfile =
        await agentsRef.doc(globals.currentUid).get();

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      ref.watch(globals.updatecompanyId());
      ref.read(globals.notifier).updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserStateProvider.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.mlsId.notifier).state =
          _currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId');
    }

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgencyProfile =
        await agencyRef.doc(ref.watch(GlobalsProvider.companyId)).get();

    if (_currentAgencyProfile != null) {
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyState.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('state');
      ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentCompanyName.notifier).state =
          _currentAgencyProfile.get('name');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool loginFail = false;
    String errorMessage = "";
    final globalVars = ref.watch(globalProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          // children: [
          //   Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png',
          //       fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
          // ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, // This fixes the keyboard white space
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 48.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect email' : null,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  errorText: loginFail ? 'incorrect passwowrd' : null,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => ResetPasswordScreen())),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Forgot Password',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        // Set the global state
                        globalVars.updatecurrentUId(currentUId: _auth.currentUser!.uid);
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Log In',
                  colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      UserCredential userCredential =
                          await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: email, password: password);

                      if (userCredential != null) {
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUid.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserId.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.uid;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUEmail.notifier).state =
                            _auth.currentUser!.email;
                        ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state =
                            0;
                        await getCurrentAgencyName();
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
                        );
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          loginFail = true;
                        });
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                      switch (error.code) {
                        case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                        case "invalid-email":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Your email address appears to be malformed.";
                          break;
                        case "email-already-in-use":
                          errorMessage = "Email is already in use.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                        case "wrong-password":
                          errorMessage = "Your password is wrong.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                        case "user-not-found":
                          errorMessage = "User with this email doesn't exist.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                        case "user-disabled":
                          errorMessage =
                              "User with this email has been disabled.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                        case "too-many-requests":
                          errorMessage = "Too many requests. Try again later.";
                          break;
                        case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                        case "operation-not-allowed":
                          errorMessage =
                              "Signing in with Email and Password is not enabled.";
                          break;
                        default:
                          errorMessage =
                              "An undefined Error happened. Please try again.";
                      }

                      if (errorMessage != null && errorMessage != "") {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            (SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage))));
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'New User?  Create Account',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => UserRegisterScreen())),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTv1tpZAGak) that explained it and I was able to figure it out from there.

I add this to the provider file:

```
final globalsNotifierProvider = NotifierProvider<GlobalsNotifier, Globals>(() {
  return GlobalsNotifier();
});
```

And then inside my ConsumerState I have:

```
getCurrentAgencyName() async {

    final globals = ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider);

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgentProfile =
        await agentsRef.doc(globals.currentUid).get();

    if (_currentAgentProfile != null) {
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecompanyId(_currentAgentProfile.get('agencyId'));
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecurrentCompanyState(_currentAgentProfile.get('state'));
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatemlsId(_currentAgentProfile.get('mlsId'));
    }

    final DocumentSnapshot _currentAgencyProfile =
        await agencyRef.doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId).get();

    if (_currentAgencyProfile != null) {
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecurrentCompanyState(_currentAgencyProfile.get('state'));
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecurrentCompanyName(_currentAgencyProfile.get('name'));
    }
  }
```